How to bundle multiple files into one minified in Vite
Trying to migrate existing Webpack mix configuration to Vite:
mix
    // CSS
    .styles([
        'resources/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'resources/css/app.css',
        'resources/sass/main.css',
        'resources/sass/dashmix/themes/xsmooth.css',
        'resources/plugins/flatpickr/flatpickr.min.css',
        'resources/plugins/select2/select2.min.css'
    ], 'public/css/app.css')
    // JS
    .js([
        'resources/js/app.js',
        'resources/js/dashmix/app.js',
        'resources/plugins/pusher/pusher.min.js',
        'resources/plugins/flatpickr/flatpickr.min.js',
        'resources/plugins/flatpickr/l10n/ru.js',
        'resources/plugins/select2/select2.min.js',
    ], 'public/js/app.js')

How to do this in Vite?
Found waleedtariq109/vite-multi-bundler repository, but unfortunately it very old and incompatible with up-to-date Vite

Why dont you use Laravel Vite Plugin?. And If you're using Laravel 9 or later, Vite is included by default
